# Neo4j match and 2 merges

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Neo4j Cypher query which is hopefully fairly obvious:

```
MATCH (n:Companies) WHERE CompanyID = $CompanyID 
MERGE (c:Countries {CountryISOCode:$CountryID}) RETURN c 
MERGE (n)-[r:MasterLink {Type:$Link}]->(c)
```

I have already created `n:Companies` so watch to match that, create a Country and then tie the two together. What am I doing wrong? (All parameters are provided)

Comment: You have not provided nearly enough information. Please update your question. Also, the error messages when you run your query should help. 1. What errors are you getting? 2. Are you using the Neo4j Browser? 3. What are you trying to do? 4. What is your data model?

Comment: Apologies - I'm running it through a PHP curl post but not seeing the Countries node or relationship through the Neo4j browser. I had assumed there was something obviously wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with this query.

- Your WHERE clause doesn't reference a node property, you need to use dot notation to indicate the node for which the predicate applies: `WHERE n.CompanyID = $CompanyID`
- The RETURN is in an invalid position. You cannot use it here in the middle of the query. It should only go at the end of a subquery, or at the end of the query itself. In this case, you can remove the RETURN entirely, unless you want something returned from the query when it finishes, in which case the RETURN should be at the very end.

Best practice here, especially when you are still learning Cypher, is to use the Neo4j Browser to ensure the syntax is correct. You can prefix the query with EXPLAIN to just make sure it compiles properly, and if not follow the error messages to correct syntax issues.